# SQL Connection Problem When Publish ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, plesk

I am so thankful for giving answer to me.

I am trying to publish my blog project. After I edit Connection String in web.config

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

is shown on my blog. How to fix this problem? Where did I make mistake?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvyhV.jpg)

Comment: Do not share sensitive info like username and passwords in your screenshots, furthermore you will need to elaborate on the error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This question isn't really related to the <sql> _language_.)

Comment: check the output window of visual studio for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing connection string in App.config